# LaunchDaemon quitting unexpectedly

Tags: php, plist, daemon, launchd

I have virtually no experience with Daemons in OS X, but managed to get one running that repeatedly runs a php file every 60 seconds.  It seems to work well, and will run for weeks at a time with no issues.  However, occasionally it will simply stop working for reasons that I haven't been able to figure out.  After this occurs, my daemon will no longer be listed in launchctl list.  If I run a launchctl start, it will begin working again with no problems.

How would I go about figuring out the reason for this seemingly random shutdown?  The php file is used to request data from an online API and update a MySQL database with the retrieved info.

Here is the contents of my plist file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple Computer//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
 <dict>
 <key>Label</key>
 <string>mschirma.automator</string>
 <key>ProgramArguments</key>
 <array>
 <string>/usr/bin/php</string>
 <string>/Library/WebServer/Documents/automator/time_log.php</string>
 </array>
 <key>StartInterval</key>
 <integer>60</integer>
 </dict>
</plist>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Launchd will remove a daemon from the list of managed daemon if it exits to often with a non-zero status code. So you need to check your PHP script and make sure it always exit with a zero status code, even in case of network or DB failure.

Comment: Thanks!  My php script would timeout when it couldn't connect to a remote API, causing exactly what you described.